# Class return value to another function in same class

Tags: php, class, variables, methods

Im trying to learn how classes work and I found a problem. How do i pass a variable from a function to another function in same class? I tried using return but it didn't work.

Here is a simple class similiar with my problem:

```
class a
{

    function one()
    {

        $var = 5;
        return $var;

    }

    function two()
    {

        $this->one();

        if($var == 5){

            echo "It works.";

        }

    }

}
```

I just wrote that directly in here, so if there is any carelessness error just ignore it.
So, how do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance! :)

**P.S Sorry if this question has already been asked, Im very bad at searching.**

Comment: You may want to hang out at the function method for a while, until you fully understand how they "share variables", or, as a matter of fact, how they don't.

Comment: Your method `one` actually returns a value but there is nothing to receive it. You need to either store the result in a class member variable or a local variable inside the `two` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're so close. You just need to capture the returned value from `a::one()` to use in `a::two()`:

```
function two(){
    $var = $this->one();
    if($var == 5){
        echo "It works.";
    }
}
```

An alternative way is to use member variables in your class:

```
class a {
    private $var;

    function one(){
        $this->var = 5;
    }

    function two(){
        $this->one();
        if($this->var == 5){
            echo "It works.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah! Thanks alot for a great and fast answer! Cheers! I'll mark it as solution as soon as the timer goes down. :) Have a great day

Comment: Saw your edit, which one do you recommend? Which one is best in which environment?

Comment: They both will work well for you. I say use option 1. As you get more experience you'll see when to use option 2.